For any $\alpha \in \pi_6 {(\mathbb{C}P^2 \vee S^2)}$, $\mathbb{C}P^2 \vee S^2 \cup_{\alpha} D^7$ has the same cohomology algebra over a field.
In the book Rational Homotopy Theory by Y. Felix, S. Halperin, and J. Thomas. Exercise 4.3 asks the reader to prove that for any $\alpha \in \pi_6 {(\mathbb{C}P^2 \vee S^2)}$, the space $X_{\alpha}=\mathbb{C}P^2 \vee S^2 \cup_{\alpha} D^7$ has the same cohomology algebra with coefficient in a field $k$.
I believe a way of doing such would be to notice that $H^n(X_{\alpha})=k$ for $n=0,4,7$,  $k^2$ for $n=2$, and trivial for other degrees. Because there does not exist a pair of generators of the cohomology groups that multiply to degree 7 via cup product (except for the identity and the generator of the cohomology of degree 7), the homotopy class of map $\alpha$ does not influence the algebraic structure of the cohomology algebra.
Is the above proof valid? Are there any errors or misunderstandings of concepts?

Note that the problem asks about the cohomology algebra, not just the cohomology groups. Your approach a priory only computes the groups.

So even if the cohomology groups of the spaces are identical the cohomology algebra with cup product as multiplication still can be different.

@JiahaoLi You have the right intuition, but to make it an actual proof, I think you need to fill in more detail. For instance, there are non-trivial cup products in lower degrees, so you might want to explain why attaching a 7-cell differently does not affect those. It’s not hard to show this by using the obvious inclusion of a subcomplex.

@JiahaoLi Yes. Consider for instance $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2$ vs. $S^2 \vee S^4$.

Your calculation of the cohomology groups is not correct. Rethink degrees 2 and 4.

Sorry I mixed degree 2 and 4 up
